# JavaFx create a chart from dataframe

Tags: java, file, javafx, charts, axis

I would like to create a chart in JavaFX. I have such a file:

[image]

And I don't know how to put "date" for x or y axis. How should I do it.
I have something like this, but I'm not sure if it is properly.

```
draw.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        newWindow.setTitle("Chart");
        //defining the axes
        if(choice1.getValue().toString()=="val" && choice2.getValue().toString()=="total"){}

        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");

        //creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        lineChart.setTitle("Chart");
        //defining a series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");
        //populating the series with data
        for(int i=0; i<d.size(); i++){
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(d.get(choice1.getValue().toString()).get(i), d.get(choice2.getValue().toString()).get(i)));
        }

        Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);
        newWindow.setScene(scene);
        newWindow.show();
     }
});

 LineChart linechart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);
    ChoiceBox choice1 = new ChoiceBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "id", "date", "total", "val")
    );
    ChoiceBox choice2 = new ChoiceBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "id", "date", "total", "val")
    );
    Button draw = new Button("Draw!");
    HBox hb = new HBox(30);
    hb.getChildren().addAll(choice1, choice2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create an example that demo's your chart. Since you attached your data as an image, I had to create fake data. In this example, I created a `DataFrame` class to hold each line of data. I added this data to a `List` named `fakeData`. I then create and name each `Series` that will be added to the `Chart`. After that, I filter the fake data by `ID`. If the filtered `ID` equals the `Series` name, I added the data to the `Series`. This chart shows `Date` to `Total`. If you need `Date` to `Val`, replace `seriesList.get(i).getData().add(new XYChart.Data(dataFrame.getDate(), dataFrame.getTotal()));` with `seriesList.get(i).getData().add(new XYChart.Data(dataFrame.getDate(), dataFrame.getVal()));`.

> Main

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartSample extends Application
{

    String alphbets = "abcdefghij";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        List<DataFrame> fakeData = generateFakeDataFrames();
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        //defining the axes
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Date");
        //creating the chart
        final LineChart<String, Number> lineChart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);
        lineChart.setTitle("Fake Chart");

        //defining a series
        List<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> seriesList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < alphbets.length(); i++) {
            XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series();
            series.setName(alphbets.charAt(i) + "");
            seriesList.add(series);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < seriesList.size(); i++) {
            char tempChar = alphbets.charAt(i);
            //Filter the fake data
            List<DataFrame> subList = fakeData.stream().filter((t) -> {
                return t.getId() == tempChar;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

            //Add the filtered data to the correct series
            for (DataFrame dataFrame : subList) {
                System.out.println(seriesList.get(i).getName() + " :" + dataFrame.getId() + "  " + dataFrame.getDate() + "  " + dataFrame.getTotal());//Check to see if data is correct.
                seriesList.get(i).getData().add(new XYChart.Data(dataFrame.getDate(), dataFrame.getTotal()));
            }
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
        lineChart.getData().addAll(seriesList);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    public List<LocalDate> createDates()
    {
        List<LocalDate> localDates = new ArrayList();

        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(1985, Month.FEBRUARY, 4);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            localDates.add(localDate.plusDays(i));
        }

        return localDates;
    }

    public List<DataFrame> generateFakeDataFrames()
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        List<DataFrame> dataFrames = new ArrayList();

        List<LocalDate> dates = createDates();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

            double total = (random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1) * 3;
            double val = (random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1) * 2000;

            dataFrames.add(new DataFrame(alphbets.charAt(i % 10), dates.get(i / 10).toString(), total, val));
        }

        return dataFrames;
    }
}
```

> DataFrame Class

```
/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class DataFrame
{

    private char id;
    private String date;
    private double total;
    private double val;

    public DataFrame(char id, String date, double total, double val)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.total = total;
        this.val = val;
    }

    public double getVal()
    {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(double val)
    {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public char getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(char id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public double getTotal()
    {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(double total)
    {
        this.total = total;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return id + ", " + date + ", " + total + ", " + date + ", " + val;
    }
}
```

[image]